# Rails - Rendering form_for @user in a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to render this code (partial to update users payment info).

/devise/registrations/_credit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<form action="#">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Card Holder Name</label>
              <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class:"form-control" %></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                <%= f.text_field :card, autofocus: false, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">CVV</label>
                <%= f.text_field :cvv, autofocus: false, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Expiration Month</label>
                <%= f.text_field :expmonth, autofocus: false, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Expiration Year</label>
                <%= f.text_field :expyear, autofocus: false, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="margin-top-10">
                 <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
              <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
            <% end %>

            <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit "Update", class:"btn green" %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get this partial to show up in a different page that's not under users_controller.rb, but I keep getting an error.

```
NameError in Orders#new
Showing /home/nitrous/code/uvesty/app/views/devise/registrations/_credit.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x00563138834928>:0x00563138821670>
```

Comment: Where are you rendering the partial? Looks like you've simply forgotten to pass the `resource` parameter.

Comment: In a different viewer that's handled by a different controller. Specifically it's in  /orders/_form.html.erb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app/models/order.rb`:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # only use this if user instance is created before order, 
  # and alway associated with order
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

---

In `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  # --OR--
  # has_one :order
end
```

---

In `app/controllers/orders_controller.rb`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # 1)assuming `current_user` is populated
  #
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  # --OR--
  # 2) assuming the following line is in `config/routes.rb`:
  #   get '/orders/new/:id' => 'orders#new'
  #
  def new
    if @order = Order.find_by_id(new_params[:id])
      @user = @order.user

    else
      # do whatever here; replace the next line
      raise "order not found"
    end
  end

  private

  # only needed for 2) above
  def new_params
    params.permit(:id)
  end
end
```

*see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters*

---

In `app/view/orders/new.html.erb`:

```
<% raise('@user not defined') unless @user %><%# <- Remove this line after partial is working %>
<%= render partial: "devise/registrations/credit", locals: {resource: @user, resource_name: :user} %>
```

*see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables*

Comment: Not sure if i'm using it wrong or not...but i get the exact same error.

Comment: @Raidspec Are you setting the `@user` in the controller like `@user = User.find(user_id)`?

Comment: Thanks bud, that fixed it. It was the user = User.first that was my issue. I had it before as 
user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: @Raidspec No prob. However, `User.first` is just there as an example, but really you want to pull the `user_id` from the `@order`, like: `@user = User.find(@order.user_id)`

Comment: The `params[:id]` you had before referenced the order ID, not the user ID, so I'll update my answer incase it helps.

Comment: @Raidspec Updated answer.

Comment: If this answers your question, consider accepting it as the answer. _see instructions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/249307_

Comment: @Raidspec Updated one last time. Notice there's two ways to set `@user` in the `orders_controller.rb`: 1) via the route param; or 2) via `current_user`